# Is there a way to determine if a user is signed in via custom firebase account or google account in flutter?

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm building a flutter app and I have options on my login page to create an account (which gets saved in firebase) or just sign in with Google (which also creates an account on firebase). On other pages, I have a logout button which only logs out of custom firebase account because it's calling this function:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
```

I also have this function for google sign out:

```
Future<void> signOutGoogle() async{
    return googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
```

variables declared at top:

```
 final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  FirebaseUser user;
```

Is there a way to determine if the user is signed in via Google or custom firebase? That way I'd be able to determine which function to call when the user clicks Logout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you should reconsider your code structure to account for different authentication types. Why don't store which authentication method did the user utilized to begin with?

Comment: that's one way to do it. I just thought of that since I keep track of enums in auth file to determine if user is signed in or not, i could keep track of type of sign in as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `FirebaseUser` property called `providerData` which type is `List<UserInfo>`. `UserInfo` has a `providerId` which is fe. `google.com`, `facebook.com`, `password` (email) or `phone`.

You can find those values looking up the [code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_provider).

```
print(user.providerData[0].providerId) // -> fe. google.com
```

Comment: ahhhh ok, I see. I'll use this method. Thank you very much.